# Open link in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I wanted to open a link in Internet Explorer even though my default browser is Google Chrome / Mozilla through javascript.**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible; it's a browser setting/behavior which is not callable from a script loaded on the page. Follow below link for more information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx